# Swift protocol of my pod wasn't available in objective-c project

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I have created a pod that declare a protocol (in swift)

I can use this protocol in my "Example project" (in swift), but when I try tu use it in a objective-c project, It's not available...

I understand my protocol should be bridge for objective-c, but it doesn't appear in `MyPod-Swift.h` file

My protocol was declared with `public` keyword.

It's the same thing for a public property (delegate) which use the type of my protocol...

I have forget to do something ? any idea ? :)

```
public protocol MyDelegate: class {
    func success(transactionId: String, amount: NSDecimalNumber)
    func failure(error: Error?, amount: NSDecimalNumber)
}
```

Solved: Should be

```
@objc
public protocol MyDelegate {
    func success(transactionId: String, amount: NSDecimalNumber)
    func failure(error: Error?, amount: NSDecimalNumber)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to prepend `@objc` to your declaration ?

```
@objc
public protocol RestoFlashDelegate {
  func success(transactionId: String, amount: NSDecimalNumber)
  func failure(error: Error?, amount: NSDecimalNumber)
}
```